# Connect an Angular Bar chart to endpoint data

Tags: angularjs, angular-chart

I am new to Angular Charts and don't have a clue how to to connect the endpoint JSON data to the graph. I followed the instructions in [AngularCharts](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/) to populate the bar chart with rough data. 
 HTML :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span12">
        <div class="widget widget-nopad">
            <div class="widget-header">
                <i class="icon-list-alt"></i>
                <h3> Skills</h3>
            </div>
            <!-- /widget-header -->
            <div class="widget-content" style="padding:5px;" ng-controller="BarCtrl">
            <canvas id="bar" class="chart chart-bar"
                        chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels"  chart-series="series">

                </canvas></div>
        </div>
    </div>


</div>
```

Controller :

```
myApp.controller('BarCtrl', ['$scope', 'reportServices', function ($scope, reportServices) {
    reportServices.getSkillsReport().then(function (result) {

        $scope.data = result.data;

        $scope.labels = ['2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012'];
    $scope.series = ['Series A', 'Series B'];

    $scope.data = [
      [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
      [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
    ];


    });
}]);
```

The output of the endpoint is :

```
{
  ".Net": 4,
  "Java": 3,
  "JavaScript": 5,
  "ASP.NET": 2,
  "Banking": 2,
  "Personal Skills": 6
}
```

Can someone please show me how to connect this data to the current default bar chart? Also I don't want the second series of bar in the chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose, your endpoint object is myobject :

```
var myobject = { ".Net": 4, "Java": 3, "JavaScript": 5, "ASP.NET": 2,"Banking": 2,"Personal Skills": 6}

$scope.labels = [];
$scope.series = ['Series A'];

$scope.data = []; 
$scope.datavalues = [];

for(i in myobject) {
   $scope.labels.push(i)
   $scope.datavlues.push(myobject[i])
}
$scope.data = [$scope.datavalues]
```

Comment: after doing that the chart just disappeared. 
myApp.controller('BarCtrl', ['$scope', 'reportServices', function ($scope, reportServices) {
    reportServices.getSkillsReport().then(function (result) {

        $scope.chartValues = result.data;

        $scope.labels = [];
    $scope.series = ['Series A'];

    $scope.data = [];
        $scope.datavalues = [];

        for (i in chartValues) {
   $scope.labels.push(i)
   $scope.datavlues.push(myobject[i])
}
$scope.data = [$scope.datavalues]


    });
}]);

Comment: you have kept 'myobject' in your code, in for loop.. change it to $scope.chartValues

Comment: Also in for loop -  for (i in $scope.chartValues)

Comment: Thanks that worked. Also I had to declare 'i' to get it running :)

Comment: Is there anyway I can put labels on X axis and Y axis to identify them easily?

Comment: You can add , chart-dataset-override="datasetOverride".. Have a look at [link](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/)

Comment: Got it! scaleLabel: {
        display: true,
        labelString: 'No. of Employees'
      }